# SQL: Minimal break to next game per team

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2016

Hello this is kindy tricky and I am struggling pretty hard. This goes way over my normal SQL skills :-) Here is the problem I am facing.

I have a gameplan. The basic structure looks like this:

```
ID     League     GameDay     GameTime    HomeTeam     AwayTeam
1        1       16.09.2018    10:00         A            B
2        1       16.09.2018    10:00         C            D
3        1       16.09.2018    14:00         E            F
4        1       16.09.2018    14:00         A            C
5        1       16.09.2018    17:00         B            D
6        1       16.09.2018    17:00         F            A
7        1       17.09.2018    10:00         E            D
8        1       17.09.2018    10:00         C            B
----> This goes on till league 6
```

I need to query now the minimal break time per Team per Day (and also per league, but the team name is unique). So in the above example Team A´s minimal break time on the 16.09.2018 would be 3 hours (the game from 17:00 minus the game from 14:00).

After a few tries I think I realized I cant do that in one query so I broke it down to one team. And created a few querys with the following result (I selected just the HomeTeam in a query, then the AwayTeam and unioned this two):

```
League      GameDay     GameTime       Team
  1        16.09.2018    10:00          A
  1        16.09.2018    14:00          A
  1        16.09.2018    17:00          A
  1        16.09.2018    10:00          A
  1        16.09.2018    10:00          B
  1        16.09.2018    17:00          B
  1        17.09.2018    10:00          B
---> And so on with the other teams
```

I have the feeling I am near the desired result but the last step is missing -.-

Comment: I thought he was asking for help to lead him into the right direction and with a bit of editing it would be better to understand. But you are right I should have skipped cause I was not 100% sure with this decission.

Comment: *Requires editing* means that **anybody** can fix the question by improving formatting or fixing minor issues. But when the OP himself has to add information (like his own efforts, which are completely missing here), then it is not EDIT, but CLOSE. Beyond that: I appreciate the quick and kind comeback. And you are right: when in doubt skip. And honestly, for the utter majority, it should be some form of CLOSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a real pain.  First, you need a list of all the games with *one* column per team:

```
select id, league, hometeam as team, gameday, gametime
from gameplan
union all
select id, league, awayteam as team, gameday, gametime
from gameplan;
```

Then, you need to bring in the *previous* gametime, calculate the datetime difference, and aggregate.

You can use a correlated subquery to get the previous date/time:

```
select gp.*,
       (select max(gp2.dametime)
        from gameplan as gp2
        where gp.gameday = gp2.gameday and
              gp.team in (gp2.hometeam, gp2.awayteam) and
              gp2.gametime < gp.gametime
       ) as prev_gametime
from (select id, league, hometeam as team, gameday, gametime
      from gameplan
      union all
      select id, league, awayteam as team, gameday, gametime
      from gameplan
     ) as gp;
```

Finally, you want the minimum difference:

```
select league, team, gamedate,
       min(datediff("minute", prev_gametime, gametime)) as minimum_break_length
from (select gp.*,
             (select max(gp2.gametime)
              from gameplan as gp2
              where gp.gameday = gp2.gameday and
                    gp.team in (gp2.hometeam, gp2.awayteam) and
                    gp2.gametime < gp.gametime
             ) as prev_gametime
      from (select id, league, hometeam as team, gameday, gametime
            from gameplan
            union all
            select id, league, awayteam as team, gameday, gametime
            from gameplan
           ) as gp
      ) as gp
group by league, team, gamedate;
```

Comment: I separated your answer in 6 querys (1. Home team, 2. Away team, 3. Union both, 4. Add previous game, 5. Calculate difference, 6. Take minimum) but in the end it worked. Thanks very much :-)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a query with an inner join on team and gameday and then calculate the time difference for each retrieved record with the below:

```
  SELECT GP1.HOMETEAM AS TEAM, GP1.GAMEDAY AS GAMEDAY, 
         CASE WHEN GP1.GAMETIME>GP2.GAMETIME THEN TIMEDIFF(GP1.GAMETIME, GP2.GAMETIME) ELSE TIMEDIFF(GP2.GAMETIME, GP1.GAMETIME) END AS TIMEDIFF
  FROM GAMEPLAN GP1 
    INNER JOIN GAMEPLAN GP2 
      ON (GP1.HOMETEAM=GP2.HOMETEAM OR GP1.HOMETEAM=GP2.AWAYTEAM) 
          AND GP1.GAMEDAY=GP2.GAMEDAY 
          AND GP1.GAMETIME!=GP2.GAMETIME
```

This will produce a number of records for each hometeam present (as it will calculate the difference for each other game played by the same team on the same day).
Also - with just this, any team that is never in the hometeam list will be missing from the result set.
So, a union is required to cover those as well (similar to the above), and then a query to get only the result with the smallest time difference:

```
SELECT MIN(TIMEDIFF), TEAM, GAMEDAY FROM (
  SELECT GP1.HOMETEAM AS TEAM, GP1.GAMEDAY AS GAMEDAY, 
         CASE WHEN GP1.GAMETIME>GP2.GAMETIME THEN TIMEDIFF(GP1.GAMETIME, GP2.GAMETIME) ELSE TIMEDIFF(GP2.GAMETIME, GP1.GAMETIME) END AS TIMEDIFF
  FROM GAMEPLAN GP1 
    INNER JOIN GAMEPLAN GP2 
      ON (GP1.HOMETEAM=GP2.HOMETEAM OR GP1.HOMETEAM=GP2.AWAYTEAM) 
          AND GP1.GAMEDAY=GP2.GAMEDAY 
          AND GP1.GAMETIME!=GP2.GAMETIME
UNION
  SELECT GP1.AWAYTEAM AS TEAM, GP1.GAMEDAY AS DAY,
         CASE WHEN GP1.GAMETIME>GP2.GAMETIME THEN TIMEDIFF(GP1.GAMETIME, GP2.GAMETIME) ELSE TIMEDIFF(GP2.GAMETIME, GP1.GAMETIME) END AS TIMEDIFF
  FROM GAMEPLAN GP1 
    INNER JOIN GAMEPLAN GP2 
      ON (GP1.AWAYTEAM=GP2.HOMETEAM OR GP1.AWAYTEAM=GP2.AWAYTEAM) 
          AND GP1.GAMEDAY=GP2.GAMEDAY 
          AND GP1.GAMETIME!=GP2.GAMETIME) T
  GROUP BY TEAM, GAMEDAY;
```

Please note - I am not entirely certain if the 'timediff' function would work like that on MS-ACCESS; you may need to revisit that.

Answer (score 1):

It won't be performant on big data, but it shoiuld work:

First it makes the union with home and away-team, then it joins with the later games and finally gets the minimum difference:

```
select team, gameday, min(breaktime) from
  (select t.team, t.gameday, g.gametime - t.gametime as breaktime from 
    (select id, league, gameday, gametime, hometeam as team from gameplan
    union 
    select id, league, gameday, gametime, awayteam as team from gameplan) t 
    join gameplan g on t.team in (g.hometeam , g.awayteam) and t.gameday = g.gameday and t.gametime < g.gametime ) breaks
group by team, gameday
```